# footer not showing or sticking to bottom - hidden behind nav, z-index not working

Tags: html, css, simple-html-dom

I have a footer, but it is not showing. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/datb3wqj/). So I want a sticky footer (footer that isn't 'fixed', but stays at the bottom), and so far it is hidden by the nav (I think). I have tried changing the `z-index` to higher than the nav, but it still stays hidden. Code:

**HTML**

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nContainer">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li class="active"><a>home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">sign up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collapse -->
    <div class="collapse">
    <h1 style="position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p class="copyright">&copy; 2015 Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #696969;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  color: #b3b3ff;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #5a5a5a;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav .active a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  cursor: default;
}

.nContainer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.collapse {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1280x720');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1
  text-align: center;
}

.collapse h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 600px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content h1 {
  color: #393c3d;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
}

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container h1 {
  margin-top: 4%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Add position to the footer css rules. Z-index doesn't work without position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not very clear - you want it to stay at the bottom, but not fixed?

I'm going to assume you want it to appear at the bottom of the *content* (i.e not fixed to the bottom of the browser) - in which case, you just have to move the footer element inside the content element.

```
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <p class="copyright">&copy; 2015 Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gqetr34

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/datb3wqj/1/)

In order for the `z-index` to work, you should first postion the div using css positioning.

so, try this CSS for your footer

```
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: this is fixed. in my question i said not fixed, but stuck to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS code with following

```
.footer {
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
   position: fixed.
}
```

You don't need z-index with `:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datb3wqj/2/)

```
.footer {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: works, but i want it to stick to the bottom of my website, not fixed to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #696969;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  color: #b3b3ff;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #5a5a5a;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav .active a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  cursor: default;
}

.nContainer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.collapse {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1280x720');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 600px;
  position: center bottom;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.collapse h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.content h1 {
  color: #393c3d;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container h1 {
  margin-top: 4%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.footer{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nContainer">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li class="active"><a>home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">sign up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collapse -->
    <div class="collapse">
    <h1 style="position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p class="copyright">&copy; 2015 Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
```